# What's with all the attempts to access \\replace_with_server_name\PIPE\sql\query in my web app?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure

I have an ASP.NET web app that uses web forms with Telerik controls and a few other libraries, runs on windows azure, and uses sql azure. I'm using Process Monitor to see what happens on the machine during application startup (trying to diagnose why the initial startup takes about 1min but that's a separate question). I see lots of CreateFile events from the w3wp.exe process hosting my app pool that have Path = `\\replace_with_server_name\PIPE\sql\query` and Result = `BAD NETWORK PATH`. Where are these coming from!?

I've searched my source code and don't find replace_with_server_name anywhere. I'll try searching through all the referenced dlls of the solution but does anyone recognise this path and have a suggestion where it might come from?

Note that `\\replace_with_server_name\PIPE\sql\query` is the exact Path that I see in Process Monitor - I haven't modified it for the purposes of this question. I'm guessing some library I'm using has this value as a default, or something like that.

Update -

I've searched through all the dll and config files in my bin directory, and through all the dlls in the .NET Framework directory and through all the config files in the .NET Framework\Config directory, but haven't found "replace_with_server_name" anywhere. I've also searched various locations like all .dlls in c:\windows\system32, all files in c:\windows\Microsoft.NET, and no luck. 
Any ideas on other places I can look? I did some of my searching using HxD editor and then I found PSPad which will do a hex search of multiple files - much quicker. I searched using Windows, ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-16 LE, and UTF-16 BE with no luck ... although it's possible I missed a couple of variations. Surely this text has to be somewhere!?

Comment: is replace_with_server_name the name of the server its running on a sql server somewhere or a totally independent server?

Comment: I've updated the question - that's the actual text that I see.

Comment: Oh, I assumed you were obfuscating your server name. :) I'd suspect there is a config file somewhere with that in, probably one that needs to talk to a sql server. Perhaps a connection string somewhere? I'm not sure... Don't recognise it myself though. :(

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateFile` Win32 API is used to open many streams including named pipes. It looks to me like something in your code is trying to created a named pipe connection to your SQL Server, but the server name specified in the connection string is 'replace_with_server_name' by default.

You might want to take a look at your config file and/or any code that describes the name of the SQL server to which you want to connect and be sure to specify the correct server name.

HTH.

Comment: 'replace_with_server_name' isn't in any of my code or config files. Must be in Telerik's, Azure's or one of the other libraries.